# C# - why am I getting an empty collection?

Tags: c#, decorator

How come people collection has items in it only if I override it within the subclasses? Here's the code. If I uncomment the overridden methods, then my collection has 2 people in the park.

```
public class Park : Thing
{
}

public abstract class Thing
{
    public virtual List<Thing> people { get; } = new List<Thing>();
}

public class PersonA : Thing
{
    Thing p;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonA(Thing p)
    {
        this.p = p;
        Name = "Marry";
        this.p.people.Add(this);
    }
    //public override List<Thing> people => p.people;
}

public class PersonB : Thing
{
    Thing p;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PersonB(Thing p)
    {
        this.p = p;
        Name = "Joe";
        this.p.people.Add(this);
    }
    //public override List<Thing> people => p.people;
}
```

And here's the test application:

```
Thing park = new Park();
park = new PersonA(park);
park = new PersonB(park);

Console.WriteLine(park.people.Count);
```

Comment: use the debugger and step through the code and you will see where you are going wrong. have you even tried that ..?

Comment: Your base class has a New List<Thing>. So it will be empty unless you override it. Try Debugging.

Comment: In the constructors, you are adding to the member `p`'s list, not the class' own list. `p.people` is not the same list as `this.people`. Unless you are trying to express that a Person _has a_ thing, it shouldn't need the `p` member.

Comment: @Uueerdo Oh that's it, makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thing park = new Park();
```

Here you are instantiating a `Park` object and assigning it to a variable whose type is `Thing`. So far, so good.

```
park = new PersonA(park);
```

Here you are instantiating a `PersonA`, and because you pass your `Park` object to the constructor, the constructor adds itself to the `Park`'s `People` collection. So that collection now contains one person. Again, so far, so good.

However, you then assign the new `PersonA` object to the `park` variable. This is not a runtime error because the variable has type `Thing` and a `PersonA` is a `Thing`, but it's almost certainly a logic error on your part, because I can't conceive of a reason why you'd want a variable called `park` that refers to a person.

The critical thing is that at this point, `park.People` doesn't refer to the `Park` object's collection of people; it refers to the `PersonA` object's collection of people, which is empty.

```
park = new PersonB(park);
```

Now when you invoke the `PersonB` constructor, you're not passing it a `Park` object; you're passing it the `PersonA` object that you assigned to the `park` variable. So the `PersonB` constructor adds itself to the `PersonA`'s `People` collection, which now contains one person.

But again, you're assigning the result to `park`. So now `park` contains a `PersonB` object whose `People` collection is empty. Which is why this:

```
Console.WriteLine(park.people.Count);
```

Prints zero.

Comment: Helpful walk through, thank you. Regarding your second paragraph, It's how decorator pattern works. You add decorators to a component. It looks a bit odd at first, but overall it makes sense and is a really useful pattern. This example is a simplified problem that I had in a much larger application.

Comment: @haosmark However, this still seems to be the source of your issue. I don't know much about decorator design pattern, but I sure know that assigning thing is the reason you're code is not working :)

Comment: @Francis Lord nah, the code wasn't working because Person was returning it's own collection, not the parent's. This is why uncommenting p.people fixes the problem.

Comment: @haosmark, understood. I'm familiar with the pattern and I'm sure the usage in your original code is a sensible one. It's just that typically the application of a decorator will produce the same "sort" of object, just with additional or modified behavior. So maybe decorating a vanilla financial calculator produces a calculator that applies delinquency fees or something. I just thought it was extremely confusing for a park to "become" a person.

Comment: @Joe Farrell well, I'm new to patterns, but from I understand this one breaks down to a component, concrete components, decorator, and concrete decorators. In the example above, Park is a concrete component, Persons are concrete decorators, and Thing is a component. I guess I could create a ThingDecorator and have the Persons extend from it, to make it more visually logical, but I decided it's redundant and didn't. I don't know if this is unorthodox, but in my inexperienced mind it fits well. The app itself is a calculator that decorates a service with labor and equipment.